# K-Means Negative Centroids Interpretation

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

Could anyone help me understanding why I am getting my k means centroids some negative values? What does that mean? I do not have any negative value in my dataset. I do not understand how to interpret the negative centroids. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Attribute   Full Data   Cluster #0  Cluster #1
 HR           0          -0.1077      0.2442
PULSE         0          -0.0954      0.2161
ABP Sys       0           0.1281     -0.2904
ICP           0           0.5302     -1.2016
RESP          0          -0.2295      0.52
CPP          85.0         85.0        92.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your *total* mean is 0, then apparently you, or the function you used, automatically normalized your data.

Comment: do u mean total mean of each column? There are not zero. I have all positive values in the dataset and Nonzero.

Comment: The "Full Data" column says your mean is 0. Your data set apparenty is different from what you think it is.